# Google Maps API Directions Not Showing Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps Directions API, this was able to work previously.

Just to clarify... The directions work, but not the Map image background:

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 34.072350, lng: -118.401209};
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 19,
        center: myLatLng
    });
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Wallis Annenberg Center for the Performing Arts'
    });

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var onChangeHandler = function () {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
}


function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
        destination: "9390 N. Santa Monica Blvd. Beverly Hills, CA 90210",
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML and CSS codes:**

```
<style type="text/css">
#map {width:1050px;height:500px;}
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Trying to follow this : 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

For this site: 
http://thewallis.org/directionsandparking.php

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

**Edit**

Some things that I did not see... _custom.css manipulates the responsiveness of Google Maps image to become important. Here's a sample code that affected the problem:

```
#map {width:1050px !important;height:500px !important;}
```

Comment: What is the problem with it?  What javascript errors do you get?  [The posted code works for me (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w6kaeedd/).  Probably a CSS issue from your description (but you didn't provide that in your question).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in the question itself**.

Comment: If you're going to check the link, you're going to see that it is not a CSS issue because you can see a brown background. I have added the CSS and HTML codes to make sure it is understandable. It could probably be a Google Maps server error, but I'm not sure. There are no errors in the console related to Google Maps API at all.

Comment: As I said, [the posted code works for me (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w6kaeedd/).  If you can make a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem, that would help us help you (and might help you discover the issue).  There is a **lot** more CSS than what you posted on the page.  The white controls in the lower right hand corner of you image are another indication of a CSS issue.

Comment: Just want to get back to this. Yes, it is a CSS issue. Apparently, the map also contains an image and got affected by the CSS code `.inner-section img:first-child`. While I did not target the map image on purpose, the first child targets each element's `img` first child, and Google Maps has images in its elements displayed as maps and buttons. Most importantly, Maps API got affected because I declared to apply width with `!important` attribute in `#map` CSS. Thus, failing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your styles for `.inner-section img:first-child`  also affect the images used by the maps-API. Find another selector(which doesn't affect the images in the map) or override these styles for the images in the map

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at the code. Yes, I noticed that `.inner-section img:first-child` affects the map because of `width:value !important;` code. Will do this tomorrow because I still need to let my work know. Will probably need to create a separate image header field for the first image, instead.